# `json_encode does not return a UTF8 character

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, json

I have a `AJAX` request sent to the PHP server, and PHP returns an array with `json_encode` back to the client.

The array is a simple 2-indexed array.

What I get from `console.log()` is this:

```
{"1":"\u00d9\u0081\u00db\u008c\u00d9\u0084\u00d8\u00af title \u00d9\u0086\u00d8\u00a8\u00d8\u00a7\u00db\u008c\u00d8\u00af \u00d8\u00ae\u00d8\u00a7\u00d9\u0084\u00db\u008c \u00d8\u00a8\u00d8\u00a7\u00d8\u00b4\u00d8\u00af.","0":"FAIL"}
```

I think this is `ASCII charset`? I don't know but I know it is not persian character!!!!

Here is my PHP code:

```
header ('Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8');
            $message = $validator->messages();
            $response[1] = utf8_encode($message->first());
            $response[0] = FAIL;
            echo json_encode(($response));
```

Though when I set the response to echo only `$message->first()` than a `json object`, it is ok and utf-8 fully

Comment: The sequences you see are Unicode Escape Sequences.  This is per the JSON spec, and any properly implemented JSON Parser in another language should read those values in correctly.  Whether or not they can be displayed or printed to a console can be affected by encoding and supported codepages on the system in question.

Comment: your ajax seems to be returning a wrong json format

Comment: The JSON looks perfectly fine, and should display normally. On a side note, are you sure `$message->first()` is encoded in `ISO-8859-1`? You cannot use `utf8_encode()` to turn *anything* into UTF-8...

Comment: I know, I use $message->first always and it is fine, I have appended the json also the an HTML element but it is the same as console.log() output

Comment: As an aside, you might have a problem on some clients since your PHP is claiming a content type of `text/html` rather than `application/json`. Actually, I think that is the actual problem, so I'll post it as an answer

Comment: dump the `$message->first()` and see if it's ISO-8859; also change the content-type to `application/json`

Comment: @MostafaTalebi do you find any solution? i have this problem too

Comment: @mohammadb Yes. First you should set the correct encoding in the HTML header (utf8). Next you should debug about utf8 characters by echoing the text (with Javascript) into the page, since in the console we get the same ugly characters and we think utf8 got problem, while the problem is with console (in my case FireBug)

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is that your PHP is claiming a content type of `text/html` rather than `application/json`. If you change the type, it will tell the browser that it should parse the content as JSON and you will get an object in your AJAX handler.